# Is it possible have vertical text and hortizonal text be side by side?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have pure HTML text rotated vertically and be sided with horizontal HTML text.

Here's a example image of what I want to do. Can someone give me an idea of how to do this?

[image]

Comment: not in a same element. this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028128/how-do-i-rotate-text-in-css

Comment: Is there any connection between the texts in different directions? Are they going to be a full sentence together? Would it be ok if you had to manually split up the text into separate elements? Or does it need to flow continuously? And what about responsiveness? Is it meant to scale in a fixed or in a fluid way?

Comment: @Mathijs Flietstra There's no connections between the texts in different directions. So it will be ok to manually split up the text into separate elements. I thought just making each line of text into blocks, but I couldn't figure out how to rotate without messing up their positions. And I should've added I want it to be responsive in a fluid way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had a go at getting something like this to work. Have a look at the result here at <kbd>**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mathijsflietstra/xkkr3/4/)**</kbd>.

I'm using a container `div` which is [set to scale while keeping its height relative to its width using this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16541664/1846192).

Inside this container `div` I have set all `div`'s to be absolutely positioned. To get the positioning of the rotated `div`'s right I have set them to stick to the left bottom corner first, set their `transform-origin` to `0 0`  and then rotated them `-90` degrees using `transform: rotate(-90deg);`, then I have moved the second rotated `div` along a little by setting its `left` property.

I'm using `em`'s for positioning to ensure the position of the `div`'s changes depending on the size of their font.

I'm using a jQuery plugin named [FitText](http://fittextjs.com/) to tune the `div`'s `font-size` properties.

I've used `transform: scale();` to stretch some of the `div`'s contents.

You'll find it will take a little tuning of the [FitText](http://fittextjs.com/) plugin settings, the `em` values of the `div`'s `top` and `left` properties and the scaling to make your texts fit. But once you've got it right it will scale beautifully when changing the width of the container `div`.

If you want to change the aspect ratio of the container, you'd have to create your own transparent image with the right aspect ratio.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <div class="container">
        <div>ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO</div>
        <div>ABCDEF</div>
        <div>ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO</div>
        <div>HELLO</div>
        <div>QRSTUVWXWZABC</div>
        <div>DEFGHIJKL</div>
    </div>
    <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6928212/threebytwo.png" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family:"Arial Black", "Arial Bold", Gadget, sans-serif;
}
body > div {
    position: relative;
}
img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
div.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    border: 1px dashed black;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div.container > div {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 1em;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
div.container > div:nth-child(even) {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform:rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    bottom: -1em;
}
div.container > div:nth-child(odd) {
    z-index: 1;
}
div:nth-child(3) {
    top: 1.1em;
    left: 1.6em;
}
div.container > div:nth-child(4) {
    left: 1em;
}
div.container > div:nth-child(5) {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 2);
    -moz-transform: scale(1, 2);
    transform: scale(1, 2);
    top: 2.8em;
    left: 3.8em;
}
div.container > div:last-child {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1, 2);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1, 2);
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1, 2);
    top: 2.3em;
    left: 2.3em;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {
    $("div.container > div:nth-child(1)").fitText(1.15);
    $("div.container > div:nth-child(2)").fitText(0.8);
    $("div.container > div:nth-child(3)").fitText(1.31);
    $("div.container > div:nth-child(4)").fitText(0.75);
    $("div.container > div:nth-child(5)").fitText(1.46);
    $("div.container > div:nth-child(6)").fitText(0.9);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I made an example:

```
<!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
<style type="text/css">.vertical{
 width: 0px;
  word-wrap: break-word;color:grey;float:left;margin-left:10px;}
.horizontal{float:left;margin-left:10px;}
</style>
</head>
  <body>
<div class="horizontal">l e t t e r s</div><br>
<div class="vertical">abc</div>
<div class="horizontal">l e t t e r s</div><br>
<div class="vertical">abc</div>
<div class="horizontal">l e t t e r s</div><br>
<div class="vertical">abc</div>
<div class="horizontal">l e t t e r s</div>
</body>
</html>
```