# CSS - vertical responsive image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have the folowing slider:

[image: Slider1]

But i have a problem with resizing it.

Right now its 1200 x 400, and when I resize the page the image **width** will resize fine. The problem is that the height stays 400px, but I want that the height also resizes relative to the width of the image when you view it on a smaller device.

How do I do that?

This is what you see on a phone:

[image: Slider2]

The css for the image right now is:

```
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

What I have tried is:

- Set the height to 33.3% (width `html`, `body` and `#container` set to `width: 100%`)
- I tried differend settings with `vh` and `vm` but did not work as I wanted it to

---

Btw:

I am using Bootstrap 4, so if there is a class in Bootstrap that can solve this would be perfect.

I also have a live version on https://jalinen.luukwuijster.io

Comment: Please give us more code, html and css for that part of page, so all css for container and for image, and also html that holds that image?

Comment: There is not really not more code that you need to know. The image is in a `<div>` and the div has a `100% height`

Comment: however, I do have a live version on: https://jalinen.luukwuijster.io

Comment: try looking here- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751565/css-100-width-or-height-while-keeping-aspect-ratio

Comment: @LuukWuijster you can add `snippet` here, or a `fiddle` link, just edit your question and add your `code` in `snippet` that would help others to help you solve this matter

Comment: What pixel is the mobile device you are using ? It's working fine for me

Comment: @L.S will you define **fine** here? his code is producing exactly same output as displayed in pic

Comment: Check my answer Luuk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did the job. Setting this elements to display block.

```
carousel-item-next, .carousel-item-prev, .carousel-item.active {
  //display: -webkit-box;
  //display: -webkit-flex;
  //display: -ms-flexbox;
  //display: flex; 

  display: block;

}
```

However, you will get a small slider on a smaller screen. What I would do is to set the `imagse` as `background-image`, then set the `background-size to cover`. This way the image will be scaled down/up from the center(or you can change from wherever you want). Then I would set `media queries` for the `height` of the slider. This way you have more control over the slider.

Comment: Hmmmmm, yes. This seems to have solved my problem.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix, just override your bootstrap and set height according to your screen size.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
#yourDiv {
    height: 200px; //or 50%;
}    

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
#yourDiv {
    height: 400px; //or 100%;
}
```

Comment: Yes ofcourse, i am familiar with the media queries, But I would just like it to be dynamic. Because If you look at it on a ipad it will still be 400px