# Image Used to Be Full Size but Now Can't Make Full Size

Tags: wordpress

This image used to be full size, but now I can't for the life of me make it full size. I have no idea what changed (I think nothing).

Code:

```
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="sell-banner"><a href="https://yodega.com/wp-
content/uploads/2017/07/storeScreenShotCicchetti.png"><img 
src="https://yodega.com/wp-
content/uploads/2017/07/storeScreenShotCicchetti.png" class="alignnone 
size-full wp-image-710" /></a></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Pic:

[image]

The pic is inside div sell-banner, and is set to full-screen image but it's clearly not.

Why could this be happening? It used to work, and just doesn't now.

Comment: Please include the CSS for the image and its containers. A [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where we can see it in action would be even better.

Comment: This is the only applicable, non-stock CSS.

.sell-banner{
    text-align:center;
    margin-bottom:1px;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up being the 'photon' portion of my Jetpack Plugin. Just had to turn off the "cache images" option.

Answer (score 1):

You Can make image Containers width to 100% And Also Make Image width 100% and Height To Auto Using CSS,Check CSS Using Inspect Element ,Like This-
[CSS: 100% width or height while keeping aspect ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751565/css-100-width-or-height-while-keeping-aspect-ratio)

Comment: Thanks for the info! The container is 100% but the image inside is sizing much smaller. How could I apply width 100% to the image inside of that div (but only that image)?

Still unsure why this changed all of the sudden when it was working correctly for days.