# Make biggest square possible in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a parent `<div>` of unknown size and I would like to create a child `<div>` of the size of the biggest square which can be contained in the parent and center this square in the middle of the parent. Is it possible with `HTML` and `CSS`?

I am aware of `max-width` and `max-height` but do not know how to ensure the aspect-ratio.

I want to be able to do something like this:

```css
.frame {
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.square {
  width: 750px;
  height: 750px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.back {
  width: 100%;
}

.front {
  width: 70.5%;
  top: 23.965%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <div class="square">
    <img class="back" src="back.png">
    <img class="front" src="front.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

But in the `square` I want the width and height set based on its parent `frame` as described. The parent `frame` can be both landscape or portrait.

Comment: Please provide your HTML and attempt

Comment: This probably does what you want? https://stackoverflow.com/a/28985475/1495198 

"This works because that the padding of an element is calculated relative to the width of its parent element"

Comment: See [Maintain the aspect ratio of a div with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css)

Comment: As far as I understand it, the padding works if only width vary, but not both width and height.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't believe that's possible - you're right that it can be solved when the screen is portrait using padding, but there's no analogue for landscape that fixes aspect ratio (afaik)

Comment: It might be possible to do it if it spans the whole screen, using 100vmin as the width and height, but for the general case of any old dimensions, probably not (unless you can solve it with `calc(100vmin - 16px)`)

Comment: @tbjgolden Thank you, while vmin does not solve the problem completely, it is at least much better than the width and heght set by px. Is there any way to refer by vmin (or something similar) to the previous element, may be iframe? (my quick test is not working...)

Comment: @fales Could you reopen the question? I found something that could be an answer https://codepen.io/tbjgolden/pen/ZEvyEBv

Comment: @tbjgolden I would like to reopen the question, but it seems to me that it is not up to me.

Comment: @tbjgolden It seems great! Thank you. Hopefully, the question will get opened, otherwise, I would try to create a new one.

Comment: Thanks for putting some code up, it helps. In particular are your images square?

Comment: @AHaworth The back.png is indeed a square, the other one is not a square.

Comment: @tbjgolden I have experimented with your code a bit and found out that there still is some width of 800px hardcoded and it can happen hence, that the square is not as big as it could be. It seems to me that a workaround of making the second image also square of the same size as the first is in the end the best possibility. However, I am still wondering if it is not possible to do something as simple as the biggest square in a rectangle in HTML/CSS.

Comment: So for my example, you'd have to create a media query that precisely describes when the containing box is portrait (the media queries are specific to the containing box): this tool might help
https://tom.bio/experiments/media-query-playground

There's no way of solving this problem without some hardcoding, but media queries can handle the switch between bounded by width and bounded by height

Comment: @tbjgolden the question has been reopened, please consider providing an answer based on your comments.

Comment: @fales added a full answer :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS: 100% width or height while keeping aspect ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78063293/3492994)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was not possible for a long time; as `padding-top:100%` and `aspect-ratio:1/1` are limited to the width (and not the height) of the container.

**BUT It is now possible; keep reading...**

## The Problem

```
███ <- square fills the width correctly
███ 
░░░ <- outer box (portrait)
░░░
```

```
███████████ \
███████████  } <- outer box (landscape) stops here
███████████ /     but square overfloweth
███████████
███████████
███████████
```

## The "Solution"

Technically, the aspect-ratio doesn't fill the width, so much as the "block direction", which in western languages is always the width...

However, we can change the `writing-mode` property to get the block direction to be height, like so:

`writing-mode: vertical-lr`

```
███░░░ <- outer box (landscape)
███░░░
 ^- square fills the height correctly
```

```
███████ 
███████ 
███████
███████
^---^
   `---- outer box (portrait) stops here, but square overfloweth
```

So now we have the opposite problem, it works in landscape but not portrait.

## The Magic

Using the right combination of media queries it should be possible to switch the writing mode at the exact dimensions it switches from portrait to landscape.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.bounds-outer {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.bounds-inner {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 90%;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.a {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1 0 1px;
  background: red;
  padding-block-start: 100%;
}

.b {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
}

/* this media query depends on layout */
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 10/9)  {
  .bounds-inner {
    writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="bounds-outer">
    <div class="bounds-inner">
      <div class="a">
        <div class="b">
          Hi
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

NOTE: Your media queries will depend on the size of the box. Verified in Chrome, Firefox and Safari.